# Retrieving the text of a message

Tags: message-coding

Is there a simple, built-in way to retrieve the text of a message, given it's identifier (such as `Power::infy`)?

The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Message.html) describes how `Message` does this: it looks for different language versions (`Power::infy::langname`), then it looks under the symbol name (`Power::infy`), then it looks under `General` (`General::infy`), then it uses `$NewMessage` ... it's pretty complicated.

Is there any built-in, hidden/undocumented way that will let me retrieve the text of a message in a simple way, without issuing the message?

I see two possibilities:

1. Reimplement the whole lookup procedure.  This is a lot of work.
2. Implement [a special stream](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/StreamMethods.html) and do something like `Block[{$Messages = ...}, Message[symb::name]]`.  Also a lot of work (implementing the stream methods), and I'm not even sure it would work.

Or maybe there is an undocumented way.  `` ?*`*Message* `` gives plenty of symbols, but it's not clear which may be interesting and what they do.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is actually straightforward. You use [`Messages[symbol]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Messages.html) to get the list, e.g.

```
Power::infy (* trigger loading the message *)
Messages[Power]
(* {HoldPattern[Power::infy] :> "Infinite expression `1` encountered."} *)
```

then, as it is a list of replacement rules, you can simply do

```
Power::infy /. Messages[Power]
(* "Infinite expression `1` encountered." *)
```

There is a bit of trickery going on here as messages are not [loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1675387/198315) until they are used, so on a fresh kernel, `Messages[symbol]` will return an empty list. However, using it as a set of replacement rules is guaranteed to work because `symbol::msg` is evaluated first, triggering the loading process before `Messages[symbol]` is executed.

Comment: I said nothing, I was confused as to how all these works. Big +1 for making me learn something new

Comment: @Rojo I learned something new, too, so it's a win for everybody.

Comment: @szabolcs it appears there is at least one case where running `MessageName[sym, name] /. Messages[sym]` does not work. And, no I don't understand why.