# How to catch complete error message information, including the message text as it would be printed?

Tags: warning-messages, message-coding, error-tracking

If I evaluate this expression:

```
Module[{}, 1/0;0^0]; msg = $MessageList
```

I get:

```
"Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >>"
"Power::indet: Indeterminate expression 0^0 encountered. >>"
{Power::infy,mrtError::function}
```

How can I collect the complete error messages in `msg`, instead of just the first part?
Something for `msg` like:

```
{"Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >>"
,"Power::indet: Indeterminate expression 0^0 encountered. >>"}
```

Some clue?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Update** See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96390/12) for a documented way to do the very same thing in v10.0 or later.

---

This method will only catch those messages which would actually get printed, not those which are [`Quiet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet.html)ed or turned [`Off`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Off.html).

We can use handlers:

```
messages = {}
clearMessages[] := messages = {}
collectMessages[m_] := AppendTo[messages, m]
Internal`AddHandler["Message", collectMessages]
```

Then do

```
clearMessages[]
1/0; 0/0;
messages
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Internal`RemoveHandler["Message", collectMessages]
```

Reference and details: [How to abort on any message generated?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1512/12)

Comment: I really do worry about my failing brain.  I was about to ask where you learned this but I've already voted on your answer in the referenced thread.  Anyway a semi-senile +1.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard you've voted ~4500 times, answered nearly 900 questions, and asked over 50 yourself. Sure, senility is the reason you can't remember what you've done before on this site. Absolutely. :)

Comment: @rcollyer I keep telling myself that but it pervades other facets of life I'm afraid.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think I'm younger than you, but I already suffer from CRS (can't remember "stuff"), and have for most of my life. So, I wouldn't worry about it. Besides, you'll forget about it in a couple of minutes anyway. :)

Comment: @rcollyer I changed my avatar to something more appropriate.  (The thing is I'm not old, I just feel like it.)

Answer (score 23):

In version 10 or later, we can use [`EvaluationData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EvaluationData.html).

```
EvaluationData[1/0; 0^0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Behind the scenes, this uses handlers, like in my first answer, meaning that only those messages will be recorded which would get printed.

Comment: Holy cow this is something I had no idea even existed.

Comment: @Pillsy It's new in v10.0, and it has not been advertised much. Those of us who started much earlier and were used to different ways of doing things would easily miss it.

Answer (score 10):

Simply you could use `$MessagePrePrint` to get the "fillers" and `$MessageList` as you did to get the message name they belong to:

```
$MessagePrePrint = Sow;

Reap[
 Module[{}, 1/0; 0^0]; $MessageList
]
```

> ```
> {{Power::infy,Power::indet},{{1/0,0^0}}}
> ```

For complete control you could go low-level and intercept `MessagePacket` as I did for:
[Prepend Information to Warning Messages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8215/121)

Comment: Or, just capture the info from `Message` [directly](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20370/52).

Comment: @rcollyer okay, I agree that's better here.

Comment: Given your new avatar, I'm compelled to bring back the Hypnotoad...

Comment: @rm-rf -- do as you wish :-)

Comment: @rm-rf that is a *very* odd toad.

Answer (score 9):

The following method will capture all messages, regardless of whether they are [`Quiet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet.html)ed or turned [`Off`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Off.html). Messages that are turned off will be wrapped in `$Off`.

You could always capture the information directly,

```
myMessageList = {};
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Message, $InMsg = False},
 Unprotect[Message];
 Message[msg_, vars___] /; ! $InMsg :=
  Block[{$InMsg = True},
   AppendTo[myMessageList, {HoldForm[msg], vars}];
   Message[msg, vars]
   ];
 (* code to run *)
 Module[{}, 1/0; 0^0]
 ];
myMessageList

(* {{Power::infy, HoldForm[1/0]}, {Power::indet, HoldForm[0^0]}} *)
```

Comment: This is all great, but this code intercepts messages that are hidden deep inside built-in functions. For example, `ParametricNDSolve` generates dozens of `General::newsym` messages when it is first called on parallel kernels. You have to block them something like this: `If[MemberQ[{HoldForm[General::newsym],
     HoldForm[FrontEndObject::notavail], HoldForm[ReplaceAll::reps],
     HoldForm[Unset::norep]}, HoldForm[msg]]
   , Return[]
   , AppendTo[msgs, {HoldForm[msg], vars}]; msgCount++;
   msgTotalCount++;
   ];` Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Messages[foo]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20032/5) to get the text of any message. With that, we can proceed as follows to extract the text of the messages that were last generated:

```
Module[{}, 1/0;0^0]; msg = $MessageList; (* last errors *)

With[{messages = ReleaseHold@
    DeleteDuplicates[# /. HoldPattern@MessageName[s_, _] :> Messages@s] &},

    # /. messages@#] &@msg
(* {{Infinite expression `1` encountered.,Indeterminate expression `1` encountered.}} *)
```

Note that you will not be able to retrieve whatever was inserted in the placeholder `` `1` `` with this.