# Plot an undefined function

Tags: plotting, version-8

When I plotted an undefined function, Mathematica also spends considerable time to process it.
It returns a blank figure necessarily. 
What confuses me is where the `Plot` spends the time.

For example, assuming that I forgeted to define the function `f`, I execute the code below.
After a moment, I will get a blank graphics.

```
Plot3D[Im@f[1/4, u + I v], {u, -2, 2}, {v, -2, 2}, Mesh -> None,  
       PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.7], Orange], ImageSize -> Large, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

During this moment, what happened to Mathematica?

Answer (score 3):

If you enclose the Plot command with Timing, you can see that it does take some time, on my computer, about 0.05 seconds.

```
 Timing[Plot3D[ ... ]]
```

You can see what it's doing using

```
 Trace[Plot3D[ ... ]]
```

The answer is that it's doing a lot! It's going through lots of possible options, lots of system calls, lots of Charting, some Legends, and then some Graphics3D=$fail. Then you get the empty plot. All that in only 0.05 seconds!

Comment: It takes 20 seconds for me!

Comment: It takes 20 seconds in Mathematica 8 and 0.04 second in Mathematica 9.

Comment: @cmc I get 2.1 and 0.03, respectively. It runs faster on 9 because it processes the function differently, figuring out it is undefined pretty quickly.

Comment: @rcollyer Those 2 seconds still seem quite excessive, and if the function is defined as `f[x_, y_] /; x > 0 && y > 0 := 1`, then it takes 2 seconds on v9 too.  Also, these 2 seconds are measured on a relatively fast computer.  I can imagine that a 5-6 year old laptop or a netbook would take 20 seconds.

Comment: @bill s, thanks for the `Trace`. I have always wondered if such a command was available (yet, never went to look for it).

Comment: @rcollyer Is it possible that lots and lots of things go wrong inside `Plot` when it gets a non-numerical value, generating myriads of messages, but the errors are simply hidden by Quiet? EDIT: [not really](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20367/how-to-catch-complete-error-message-information/20371#20371)

Comment: @Szabolcs my suspicion is that it is the difference between numeric and symbolic processing. That latter always takes longer. Why isn't it shortcircuited earlier? I can't speculate.