# Need help with exception handling

Tags: programming, warning-messages, message-coding, error-trapping

I have read the docs for `Catch`, `Throw`, and friends multiple times, and I confess that I find them utterly incomprehensible...

Can someone tell me how one would port the following Python snippet to Mathematica?

```
def safeeval(fn, x, epsilon=sys.float_info.epsilon):
    try:
        # first attempt
        return fn(x)
    except Exception, first_exception:
        try:
            try:
                # second attempt
                return fn(x + epsilon)
            except:
                # third (and last) attempt
                return fn(x - epsilon)
        except:
            # give up!
            raise first_exception
```

In words: return `fn(x)`, trapping any exceptions during the evaluation of `fn(x)`.  If there is an exception, cache it in `first_exception`, and return `fn(x + epsilon)`, again trapping any exceptions.  If there is again an exception (a second one), return `fn(x - epsilon)`.  Lastly, if there is again an exception (a third one), give up and re-raise `first_exception`.

A higher-level, less literal translation of the above would be this: return the first one of `fn(x)`, `fn(x + epsilon)`, and `fn(x - epsilon)` that evaluates without errors (*silencing any errors that do occur along the way*).  If none of these expressions evaluates without errors, then proceed exactly as with the usual evaluation of `fn(x)` (emitting the appropriate error messages, etc.).

---

EDIT: OK, I finally came up with a solution that approximates what I described above, though I'm not sure it's anywhere close to optimal:

```
safeEval[fn_, x_, epsilon_:$MachineEpsilon]:= Module[{v, sentinel},
    v = Quiet[Check[fn[x],
                    Check[fn[x+epsilon],
                          Check[fn[x-epsilon],
                                sentinel]]]];
    If[v =!= sentinel, v, fn[x]]
]
```

I was (*ahem*) thrown off by the whole `Catch`, `Throw` nomenclature.  (These functions now seem to me like something unnaturally tacked onto Mathematica to make it look more like other more widely known languages.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know Python, and there's one aspect of the Python code I don't get; but this does what the last paragraph describes.

```
safeeval[fn_, x_, epsilon_] :=
 ReleaseHold @ Catch @ Quiet @
    Check[
     fn[x],
     Check[
      ReleaseHold @ Catch @ Quiet @
         Check[
          fn[x + epsilon],
          Throw @ Hold[fn[x - epsilon]]],
      Throw @ Hold[fn[x]]]]
```

I don't see how to re-enter the first `f[x]` from the point of the last `Throw` without creating an infinite loop.  That's the part of the Python code I don't understand: re-raising `first_exception`.  It certainly looks easier in Python.  Perhaps someone will come up with a more elegant solution.

*Examples*

First try succeeds

```
safeeval[# &, 0, 1]
(* 0 *)
```

Second try succeeds

```
safeeval[1/# &, 0, 1]
(* 1 *)
```

Third try succeeds

```
safeeval[1/(# (# - 1)) &, 0, 1]
(* 1/2 *)
```

Default case - all failed

```
safeeval[1/0 &, 0, 1]
```

> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >>

```
(* ComplexInfinity *)
```

---

**Edit: Cacheing the error messages**

Applying one of the answers to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20367/how-to-catch-complete-error-message-information), one can easily adapt the above to cache the error messages from the first evaluation of `f[x]` and avoid having to evaluate it twice.

```
Module[{messages = {}},
  clearMessages[] := messages = {};
  collectMessages[m_] := AppendTo[messages, m];
  printMessages[] := ReleaseHold @ messages;
  ];
safeeval[fn_, x_, epsilon_ : $MachineEpsilon] :=
 Module[{retval},
  ReleaseHold @ Catch @ Quiet @
     Check[
      clearMessages[];
      Internal`AddHandler["Message", collectMessages];
      retval = fn[x];
      Internal`RemoveHandler["Message", collectMessages];
      retval,
      Check[
       ReleaseHold @ Catch @ Quiet @
          Check[
           fn[x + epsilon],
           Throw @ Hold[fn[x - epsilon]]],
       Throw[Hold[printMessages[]; retval]]
       ]
      ]
  ]
```

Comment: I think this would more in accord with the Python code if it were written `safeeval[fn_, x_, epsilon_:$MachineEpsilon] := ...`

Comment: I thought of that, but since I don't know Python, I didn't want to assume what `epsilon` was.  I hoped the OP knew about `$MachineEpsilon` already.  But thanks anyway! (+1 on the comment. :)

Comment: Thanks!  I came up with a solution very similar to yours (see my EDIT), though I can't follow your use of `Hold`, `ReleaseHold`, etc.  I guess that their role has something to do with preserving the whole `Catch`/`Throw` scheme?  As I alluded to in my EDIT, this scheme seems like something shoehorned into Mathematica for basically PR purposes...

Comment: @kjo The `Hold` is so that `f[x]` is not evaluated inside the `Quiet`.  `ReleaseHold` removes the `Hold` after the `Catch`; at that point, `f[x]` will be evaluated, outside `Quiet`. == You're solution seems reasonable.  One defect (IMO) of both of ours is that `f[x]` is evaluated twice in the worst case.

Comment: @MichaelE2: it would be very easy to avoid re-computing `f[x]` (simply replace the first evaluation of `f[x]` with an assignment to some caching module variable of the result of this evaluation, e.g. `Quiet[Check[memo = f[x], Check[...]]]`.)  What I can't readily figure out how to do is to faithfully repeat the messages emitted during this first evaluation of `f[x]`.  In the end this is why I resorted to repeating the evaluation of `f[x]`.

Comment: @kjo See update. (The second half of your comment is what I meant about evaluating `f[x]` twice.)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you already have your solution, and a rather elegant one at that, but perhaps what is yet lacking is a convenient method that does not require manually writing that nested structure.

We can use recursion.  The basic form looks like this:

```
SetAttributes[errorTry, HoldAll]

errorTry[a_, b__] := Quiet @ Check[a, errorTry[b]]

errorTry[x_] := x
```

You would use it like this:

```
fn[1] := (1/0; 1)
fn[2] := (1/0; 2)
fn[3] := (1/0; 3)

errorTry[fn[1], fn[2], fn[3], fn[1]]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

With this simple form you do have to specify the first expression twice, and it is also evaluated twice in the fall-through case.  To address these issues we might use:

```
SetAttributes[errorTry2, HoldAll]

errorTry2[a_, b___] := Module[{x}, errorTry[x = a, b, x]]
```

Use:

```
errorTry2[fn[1], fn[2], fn[3]]
```

If you wish to return the error messages for `fn[1]` in fall-through you could either simply reevaluate that expression, or if that is costly you can cache.  The simple approach would look something like this:

```
SetAttributes[{errorTry3, eT3}, HoldAll]

errorTry3[a_, b___] := eT3[a, b] /. eT3[] :> a

eT3[a_, b___] := Quiet @ Check[a, eT3[b]]
```

Use as above.  Finally, the complete self-contained function with caching:

```
SetAttributes[errorTry4, HoldAll]

errorTry4[a_, b___] :=
  Module[{f, x, msg = {}},
    SetAttributes[f, HoldAll];
    f[i_, j___] := Quiet @ Check[i, f[j]];
    Block[{Message = AppendTo[msg, {##}] &}, x = a];
    If[msg === {}, x, f[b] /. f[] :> (Message @@@ msg; x)]
  ]
```

I hope this gives you all the options you could want.

Comment: There are a lot of very cool ideas in that reply.  Thanks!

Comment: @kjo You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple implementation of Java try/catch/finally, translated in Try/Failure/Finally

```
(* Mathematica Package *)


BeginPackage["Language`"]
(* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- *)
(*
    Try/Failure/Finally
    Failed/$Return/$Failure

    Try[
        body, 
        Failure[form, cbody], 
        ...
        Finally[fbody]
    ] 

where

    Failed[tag] == Throw[$Failed, tag]

    Failed[c::m, args___] == Throw[$Failed, Hold[c::m, {args}]]

    It is possible modify the result generated in 'body' by assign a new
    value to the symbol '$return'. 

    With 'Throw[result, tag]', the result of the expression is 'result'
    (o '$Failed' if you use 'Failed[tag]').
        The value 'result' will be assigned to '$Return' 

    Try[]                   == Try[Null]
    Try[body, Failure[...]*, Finally[...]?]

    Failure[]               == Failure[_, Null]
    Failure[form]           == Failure[form, Null]
    Failure[form, ebody]

    Finally[]               == Finally[Null]             
    Finally[fbody]

    form: a pattern
    tag:  a expression
    body, ebody, fbody: a expression

    La valutazione procede come segue:

    1) viene valutato 'body' (Try[body, ...])
    2) se non ci sono eccezioni, il risultato viene assegnato a $Return
        3) se e' presente la sezione 'Finally[fbody]' viene valutato 'fbody'
        4) - se in 'fbody' non viene assegnato un nuovo valore a '$Return' e ritorna
         Null, allora il risultato e' il corrente valore di $Return
           - se in 'fbody' viene assegnato un nuovo valore a '$Return' e ritorna 
         Null, allora il risultato e' il nuovo valore di $Return
           - se 'fbody' ritorna un valore diverso da Null, allora questo e' il nuovo
             valore dell'espressione
        5) in caso di eccezione (generata con 'Throw[value, tag]' oppure 'Failure[tag]'
           che e' equivalente a 'Throw[$Failed, tag]'), il valore di '$Return' e'
           'value' o '$Failed'.
    6) vengono scandite le sezioni 'Failure[form, cbody]' alla ricerca della 
       prima in cui 'form' ha un match con 'tag':
       - se non viene trovata, l'eccezione viene propagata ma VIENE valutata la
         sezione 'Finally[fbody]' se presente
       - se viene trovata, viene valutato 'cbody', che segue le stesse regole 
         di 'fbody'
       - se e' presente la sezione 'Finally[fbody]' la valutazione procede
         come indicato al punto 4 
    7) l'esatta eccezione sollevata (tag) si puo' trovare nei blocchi 'Failure[]' 
       e 'Finally[]' nella variabile '$Failure'

    Le variabili '$Failure' e '$Return' usano 'dynamic scoping' ('Block[...]')

    In 'ebody' e' possibile utilizzare eventuali pattern definiti in 'form'
*)
(* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- *)

$Return::usage="Usable in 'body' on 'Failure[]' and 'Finally[]' to change the \
  return value, but 'body' MUST return 'Null'. Otherwise the new value returned \
  is the value of the body evaluation";

$Failure::usage="Contains the exception generated";

Try::usage="Try[body, Failure[form, ebody]*, Finally[fbody]?] execute 'body' and \
  'fbody' if present. 
  If 'body' generate a exception (using Throw[.., tag]) the next expression \
  evaluated is the first 'ebody' of the 'Failure[form, ebody]' list where 'form' \
  match 'tag'";

Failed::usage="Failed[tag] == Throw[$Failed, tag]\
      Failed[c::m, args___] === Throw[$Failed, Hold[c::m, {args}]]";

Failure::usage="Failure[tag, ebody] | Failure[tag] | Failure[]"

Finally::usage="Finally[fbody] | Finally[]";


(* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- *)
(*                                                                         *)
(* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- *)

Begin["`Private`"]

Unprotect[
   Try, Failure, Finally, 
   Failed, $Return, $Failure
];

(* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- *)
(*
    Try[]               == Try[Null]
    Try[body, Failure[...]*, Finally[...]?]

    Failure[]           == Failure[_, Null]
    Failure[form]       == Failure[form, Null]
    Failure[form, ebody]

    Finally[]           == Finally[Null]             
    Finally[fbody]

    form: un pattern
    tag:  un'espressione
*)
(* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- *)

SetAttributes[Try, HoldAll];
SetAttributes[Failed, HoldFirst];
SetAttributes[HandleFailures, HoldAll];


(* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- *)
(* Failed                                                                  *)
(* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- *)

Failed[fail_] := Throw[$Failed, Evaluate[fail]];

Failed[message:MessageName[category_, _], args___] :=
    With[{mh = Hold[message, {args}]}, 
        Message[message, args];
        Throw[$Failed, mh];
    ];


(* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- *)
(* Try                                                                     *)
(* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- *)

Try[body_:Null, Longest[failures___Failure], finally_Finally:Finally[]] :=
    Block[{$Return=Null, $Failure=Null}, 
        Catch[
            HandleBody[body], 
            _, 
            HandleFailures[#1, #2, Hold[failures]]&
        ];
        HandleFinally[finally];
        Return[$Return];
    ];


(* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- *)
(* HandleBody                                                              *)
(* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- *)

HandleBody[body_] := 
    With[{}, 
        $Return=Evaluate[body]
    ];


(* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- *)
(* HandleFailures                                                          *)
(* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- *)

(*
    Param failures: Hold[failure, ...]

    failure ::= Failure[]          == Failure[_, Null]
                Failure[form]      == Failure[form, Null]
                Failure[form, body]
*)
HandleFailures[return_, tag_, failures_]:=
    Module[{i, n=Length[failures]}, 
        $Return=return;
            $Failure=tag;
        For[i=1, i<=n, ++i, 
            With[{failure=failures[[i]]}, 
            If[Length[failure]==0, Return[$Return]];     (*Failure[]*)
            With[{form=failure[[1]]},               (*Failure[form, body?]*)
            If[MatchQ[tag, form], 
                Return[HandleFailure[tag, failure]];
            ]]];
        ];
        Throw[return, tag];
    ];

(*
    Failure[form]      == Failure[form, Null]
    Failure[form, body]
*)
HandleFailure[tag_, Failure[form_, body_:Null]] :=
    With[{return=tag/.form->body}, 
        If[return =!= Null, $Return=return];
            Return[$Return];
    ];


(* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- *)
(* HandleFinally                                                           *)
(* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- *)

(*
    Finally[]     == Finally[Null]
    Finally[body]
*)
HandleFinally[Finally[body_:Null]] :=
    With[{return=Evaluate[body]}, 
        If[return =!= Null, $Return=return];
            Return[$Return];
    ];


(* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- *)
(*                                                                         *)
(* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- *)

Protect[
   Try, Failure, Finally, 
   Failed, $Failure, $Return
];

End[]

Print["Language`TryCatch` Installed"]

EndPackage[]
```