# Echoing commands when running packages in batch mode

Tags: output, command-line

I run Mathematica packages in batch mode. I need a log file showing input commands and displaying their output.

I tried these commands

```
slogf = OpenWrite["logfile.log"] 
AppendTo[$Output, slogf]
AppendTo[$Echo, slogf]
```

However, 'logfile' contains only some output.

Any hint?

Comment: You may want to redirect messages to the log file too, i.e. add the log file as a destination to `$Messages`. Take a look at the suggestions here: [How to record all the output (including error messages) of a mathematica script in a file?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47835/27951).

Comment: Thank you MarcoB. I tried your suggestions, beside those in the previous answer that you quoted. Unfortunately I was not able to obtain echo input in log file, nor error echo.

Answer (score 1):

support@wolfram.com clarified me that batch-processing is different from notebook processing.
I partially solved my problem by implementing a shell script, which interprets my packages line-by-line.
The inconvenience is that you must provide .m files where each line issues a single, complete command.
Have a nice work.