# How to stop Mathematica from turning off warning messages in a loop?

Tags: warning-messages, message-coding

I'm using `NonLinearModelFit` on a large set of data and which contains a nested Do-loop. I'd like to see all of the cases where there is an issue with the non-linear model fit, but after about five of these messages, further warnings are suppressed. Is there some way to make sure it doesn't suppress these messages after repeated warnings along the way?

```
z = NonlinearModelFit[trimspectra, a (x/x0)^(-b + c (Log[x/x0])), {a, b, c}, x];
```

Comment: From the docs on `Message`: *`Off[General::stop]` makes the Wolfram Language not stop repeating messages.*  -- You might also be interested in `Check`. It can respond to messages even though the printing has stopped. -- Also perhaps of interest to you: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20367/how-to-catch-complete-error-message-information

Comment: Yes, Thank you Michael, Message: Off[General::stop] did the trick. When I get a message, is there a simple way to print out a variable to tell me where in the do-loop the issue occurred? Such as If[MessageList[-1]!={}, Print["Variable = ", variableOfInterest] ] ?

Comment: I just tried the If statement inside the loop. Outside the loop, it printed in a test case, but inside the loop, no printing.  NonlinearModelFit::sszero: is my error warning. z = NonlinearModelFit[trimspectra, a (x/x0)^-b, {a, b}, x];
If[MessageList[-1] != {}, Print["LST = ", lst]];

Comment: The Q I linked to has a good method.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Szabolcs's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20371/4999) to [How to catch complete error message information, including the message text as it would be printed?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20367/how-to-catch-complete-error-message-information):

```
report[m_] := If[NumericQ[i], Print[HoldForm[i] == i]];
Internal`AddHandler["Message", report];
Off[General::stop];

Do[
 1/Mod[i, 3],
 {i, 15}]

On[General::stop];
Internal`RemoveHandler["Message", report]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can also do the following if you know where the error might occur:

```
Do[
 Check[1/Mod[i, 3], Print[HoldForm[i] == i]],
 {i, 15}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks again - the last section did it for me, but the 1st two sections are helpful in general for when I'd like to collect the messages. (-:

Comment: @Szabolcs Sorry!

Comment: @MichaelE2 Don't worry about it, I know the spelling looks very strange :-)

Comment: Is there an easy modification to avoid the suppression of a specific error message? For example `DeleteFile::fdnfnd`.