# Programmatically assign output Hold[...] produced by errors to a variable

Tags: assignment, message-coding

```
expr = Return[1, 2]
```

> Return::nofunc: Function 2 not found enclosing Return[1,2]. >>

```
(*Hold[Return[1, 2]]*)
```

However, `Hold[Return[1, 2]]` is not assigned to `expr`.Why does this happen? I want to use some code to store the output into that variable, is it possible?

PS: Please don't manually copy/paste or use methods like read the output cells/notebook contents and its variation. I prefer dealing with the problem directly.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20367)?

Comment: @J.M. Thanks, that does captures the Expression in error message. But I still wonder why the output is not assigned to the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expressions that simply evaluate with messages are not returned wrapped in `Hold`, and there is no problem assigning these to a Symbol:

```
expr = Map[1, 2, 3, 4];

?expr
```

> Map::nonopt: Options expected (instead of 4) beyond position 3 in Map[1,2,3,4]. An option must be a rule or a list of rules. >>
>
> ```
> Global`expr
>
> expr = Map[1, 2, 3, 4]
> ```

Your use of [`Return`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Return.html) however breaks the normal evaluation order much as [`Throw`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Throw.html) or [`Break`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Break.html) would, so `Set` is never completed.  This is really no different from wondering why `Print` does not print `"foo"` or `"bar"` in:

```
Print["foo", "bar", Return[1, 2]]
```

> Return::nofunc: Function 2 not found enclosing Return[1,2]. >>
>
> ```
> Hold[Return[1, 2]]
> ```

If you explain how this output is originating perhaps I can recommend a work-around.

Comment: Thanks! My original case was that, I was swapping a head to `Return` in an expression like `head@@{1,2}` and I wanted to extract information in list `{1,2}`, but since the assignment failed, I have to change to other methods.