# How to get a list of indices at which errors occur during iteration

Tags: warning-messages, error-tracking

I have been looking at some of the questions regarding error handling but i think my problem is unique.

I am running a Do-loop. I get errors only for certain values of the loop variable due to the nature of the problem.

Example

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
b = {2, 0, 40, 5, 0};
x = {};
Do[Append[x, a[[i]]/b[[i]]], {i, 1, 5}]
```

At iterations 2 and 5 the above code gives the error message

> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >>

I want to know at which index value an error occurs -- any error, not only the particular error given it the example -- and I want to store those values in a variable. I have looked at documentations for `Check`, `Catch`, etc., but I couldn't see how to use them. Is there a way to do this?

#### EDIT

My program is pretty much complex than the above example and has to use loops. So an answer with loops is appreciable.

Comment: Can't you get an `If[]` statement in there?
Loops are discouraged in Mathematica though...

Comment: You certainly meant `AppendTo` instead of `Append`. But anyways, as @Feyre said, use `Table` instead of `Do`. And read the documentation more thoroughly.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way to do it:

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; b = {2, 0, 40, 5, 0}; 
x = Quiet[Table[a[[i]]/b[[i]], {i, 1, 5}]];
Position[x, ComplexInfinity]
{{2}, {5}}
```

Basically, `ans` contains the values plus the errors, which in this case are `ComplexInfinity`. You can locate the errors using Position, in this case, at positions 2 and 5. If you want to check for any old error, you can use `Check`:

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; b = {2, 0, 40, 5, 0};
x = Quiet[Table[Check[a[[i]]/b[[i]], $Failed], {i, 1, 5}]];
Position[x, $Failed]
```

`Check` returns the first argument (in this case `a[[i]]/b[[i]]` if there is no error and returns the second argument (in this case the symbol `error`) if there is an error. Thanks to J.M. for suggesting using the already defined symbol `$Failed`.

Comment: Hi @bill s, the error ComplexInfinity is for that particular case. Is there any way to generalize it?

Comment: See updated answer for more general error checking...

Comment: I would prolly use the built-in `$Failed` instead of introducing a new global symbol.

Answer (score 4):

Another way (see [How to catch complete error message information, including the message text as it would be printed?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20367/how-to-catch-complete-error-message-information) for more ways to hack messages):  This works because `i` is effectively [`Block[]`-ed](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) by `Do[]`.

```
badindices = {};
$MessagePrePrint = (AppendTo[badindices, i]; #) &;

Do[Append[x, a[[i]]/b[[i]]], {i, 1, 5}]

$MessagePrePrint = Automatic;
badindices

(*  {2, 5}  *)
```

As function for running code: This collects the value of an expression `expr` at the time a message is generated.

```
SetAttributes[checkrun, HoldAll]
checkrun[code_, expr_] :=
 Module[{exprlist = {}, res},
  $MessagePrePrint = (AppendTo[exprlist, expr]; #) &;
  res = code;
  $MessagePrePrint = Automatic;
  {res, exprlist}
  ]
```

Example:

```
i = 100;  (* to show  i  is  Block[]-ed *)
checkrun[
 Do[Append[x, a[[i]]/b[[i]]], {i, 1, 5}]
 , i]

(*  {Null, {2, 5}}  *)
```

Comment: Note: I tried [Szabolcs' `collectMessages`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20367/how-to-catch-complete-error-message-information/20371#20371), altered to store `i`, but I got [spurious internal syntax-error messages](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0DCqE.png).

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to use `Quiet` and need to know which error messages were generated during the evaluation, you can use `$MessageList`. Starting from your code:

```
Module[{errors = Internal`Bag[{}], mess, a, b, x}, 

    a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    b = {2, 0, 40, 5, 0};
    x = {};

    Block[{$MessageList = {}},
       Do[
          Quiet[
             AppendTo[x, a[[i]] / b[[i]]];
             mess = $MessageList
          ];
          If[mess =!= {},
             Internal`StuffBag[errors, i -> mess];
             mess = $MessageList = {}
          ],
          {i, 1, 5}
       ];
       {x, Internal`BagPart[errors, All]}
    ]

]
```

This will evaluate to:

```
(*
{{1/2, ComplexInfinity, 3/40, 4/5, ComplexInfinity}, 
 {2 -> {Power::infy}, 5 -> {Power::infy}}
}
*)
```

I am using a bag (with `` Internal`Bag ``, `` Internal`StuffBag ``, `` Internal`BagPart ``), but this can be replaced by lists or associations with the appropriate functions for filling them.

Answer (score 2):

[`Check`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Check.html) is the function supplied with Mathematica for doing what you request. Here is how it can be used in your situation.

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
b = {2, 0, 40, 5, 0};
Quiet @ Module[{errs = {}, vals},
  vals =
    Table[Check[a[[i]]/b[[i]], AppendTo[errs, i]; Nothing], {i, 5}];
  {vals, errs}]
```

> `{{1/2, 3/40, 4/5}, {2, 5}}`

Comment: This seems, as you suggest, a very natural way. For other users, a couple of remarks to show how it can be adapted: (1) It works with `Do` if one's use-case is not to generate a `Table`. One can omit `Nothing`, in this case. (2) One can add `res` to the `Module` and use `Check[res = a[[i]]/b[[i]], AppendTo[errs, i]; res]` to get a table of all results, including the erroneous ones. (Upvoted earlier.)

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`Check`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Check.html) and [`$MessageList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$MessageList.html).

```
x = MapThread[Check[#1/#2, Last@$MessageList] &, {a, b}]
(* {1/2, HoldForm[Power::infy], 3/40, 4/5, HoldForm[Power::infy]} *)
```

Indices of errors can be obtained by:

```
errs = Position[x, HoldForm[MessageName[__]]]
(* {{2}, {5}} *)
```

and extracted by:

```
Extract[x, errs]
(* {HoldForm[Power::infy], HoldForm[Power::infy]} *)
```

The above is easily converted for loops if you really really need that.

Hope this helps.