# Internal function overload when calling ReadString on a fresh kernel

Tags: functions, warning-messages, built-in-symbols, usage-messages

**Problem description:**

I am capturing all FE messages to redirect them to my own window while blocking them from showing in the  evaluation notebook using [this method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20370/44141) by rcollyer. It works great, but I have noticed a strange thing. If my code includes [`ReadString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReadString.html), then my custom error window is flooded with a lot of messages:

```
The function run has already been loaded with argument types {Integer,UTF8String,UTF8String,UTF8String,UTF8String}. The new function will be an overload for different types.
```

This happens only the first time with a fresh kernel (or after [`Quit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quit.html)). The second and all consecutive calls to [`ReadString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReadString.html) with the same or other arguments work fine without any errors. There are no errors as well if I call [`ReadString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReadString.html) with any arguments even one time on a fresh kernel prior to message capturing, which means it has something to do with the initial loading of built-in functions.

I have experimented with other functions (I/O such as [`Read`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Read.html), [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html), and standard [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html), [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html)etc., and even [`WriteString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WriteString.html)), but none of them produces that error.

This is the simplified version of the code that generates the same behavior (using [`Print`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print.html) here for simplicity and retaining [`Message`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Message.html)to display all messages in the evaluation notebook for debugging -- not using it in the main code):

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Message, $InMsg = False}, Unprotect[Message];
 Message[msg_, vars___] /; (! $InMsg && msg =!= $Off[]) := 
  Block[{$InMsg = True, controlstring},
   controlstring = 
    First@ReleaseHold[
      msg /. Cases[HoldPattern@msg, 
        HoldPattern[MessageName[x_, _]] :> Messages@x]];
   Print[StringForm[controlstring, vars]];
   Message[msg, vars];
   ];
 Module[{}, ReadString["ew"]];
 ]
```

The message name for this error is `LibraryFunction::overload`, but the strange thing is that `msg` doesn't get that value, instead it is set to the control string already, the same we can find by calling `Messages[LibraryFunction]`. In this example code, I am still allowing for the messages to be displayed normally through [`Message`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Message.html), which shows all messages (including the message that a file cannot be opened) except for this one, so we see it only because of [`Print`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print.html), but it is also why my custom window gets all those errors, as I am using the `controlstring` variable. Is there a hidden reason why [`Message`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Message.html) doesn't print this error?

**The questions are:**

1) Why is [`ReadString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReadString.html)so special and what is that error?

2) Are there other functions like that? I can of course, call [`ReadString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReadString.html)with a dummy parameter before I set up message capturing to make sure it is loaded, but what if there are other functions with a similar behavior? I don't want to see the internal messages that are normally not visible in the front end -- [`Message`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Message.html) doesn't print it under normal circumstances.

3) What can be done to eliminate that error -- e.g. pre-loading some packages etc.? Other versions of the code that allows for message capturing (and also preventing it from displaying normally, so [`EvaluationData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvaluationData.html)wouldn't work here)?

Comment: About 3). Just *touch* the symbol before you do something. This means a simple `ReadString;` preceding your code block preloads the library function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(analysis current as of version 11.1)*

**1) Why is ReadString so special and what is that error?**

In a fresh kernel, `ReadString` is auto-loaded from the `` ProcessLink` `` package.  In that package, `LibraryFunctionLoad` is used to create 201 overloads for the external `libProcessLink` function `run`.  Those overloads allow a potentially large variable number of command line arguments to be passed to an external process.  On every call to `LibraryFunctionLoad` but the first, the warning message `LibraryFunction::overload` is issued.  These are only warnings, and the code explicitly uses `Quiet` to suppress them.

All of this can be observed by inspecting the definition of the symbol `runs` in the file:

```
NotebookOpen @ FileNameJoin @
  { $InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Links", "ProcessLink", "ProcessLink.m"}
```

As [rcollyer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/52/rcollyer) notes in the [linked post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20370/142), the code there will capture all messages, even those suppressed by `Quiet` or `Off`.  The code in the present question ignores `Off` cases, but still captures quieted messages.  It is such quieted messages that we are seeing here.

**2) Are there other functions like that?**

I am sure that there are many -- any functions that intentionally `Quiet` messages.  At the very least, all of the other functions auto-loaded along with `ReadString` will exhibit the same behaviour:

```
(* in a fresh kernel *)
OwnValues[ReadString]

(* { HoldPattern[ReadString] :>
       Package`ActivateLoad[
         ReadString,

         (* these functions: *)
         {ProcessEnvironment, ProcessDirectory, WriteLine,
          ReadLine, ReadString, EndOfBuffer, $SystemShell, Processes,
          ProcessObject, ProcessStatus, ProcessInformation,
          ProcessConnection, KillProcess, RunProcess, StartProcess},

         "ProcessLink`",
         {Package`HiddenImport -> False, Path -> Automatic}
       ]
   } *)
```

**3) What can be done to eliminate that error?**

If our intention is to capture quieted messages, then the behaviour we see is correct.  Otherwise, we can find a way to identify quieted messages.

We can use the undocumented function `` Internal`QuietStatus `` to check whether a message has been intentionally quieted:

```
Quiet[Internal`QuietStatus[], LibraryFunction::overload]

(* { Global -> Unquiet,
     Off -> {HoldForm[LibraryFunction::overload]},
     On -> {},
     Stack -> {{2443, {HoldForm[LibraryFunction::overload]}, {}}},
     MessageList -> {},
     Check -> None
   } *)
```

We could incorporate this information into a further check in our example code.  For instance:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Message, $InMsg = False}
, Unprotect[Message]
; Message[msg_, vars___] /; !$InMsg
                         && msg =!= $Off[]
                         && FreeQ[Off /. Internal`QuietStatus[], Unevaluated[msg]]
                         := 
    Block[{$InMsg = True, controlString}
    , controlString =  msg /. m:HoldPattern[MessageName[f_, _]] :> (m /. Messages[f])
    ; Print[StringForm[controlString, vars]]
    ; Message[msg, vars]
    ]
; ReadString
]
```

Naturally, the use of undocumented functionality comes with no support guarantees.

**Bonus Question: Why is *msg* a string instead of a *MessageName*?**

The value of *msg* at the time the function is invoked is in fact a `MessageName`, but as soon as it is evaluated the result is a string:

```
LibraryFunction::overload

(* "The function `1` has already been loaded with argument types `2`. \
    The new function will be an overload for different types." *)
```

This follows the convention for defining messages in high-level code.  On the other hand, built-in kernel functions do not always have user-visible definitions and this includes message definitions:

```
Map::nonopt

(* Map::nonopt *)
```

Many messages, even ones for built-in kernel symbols, are not available until the message has been evaluated (to trigger auto-loading):

```
(* from a fresh kernel *)

Messages[Map]
(* {} *)

Map;
Messages[Map]
(* {} *)

Map::nonopt;
Messages[Map]
(* {{HoldPattern[Map::nonopt]:> "..."} *)
```

Fortunately, these corner cases can be addressed by a relatively simple expression:

```
msg /. m:HoldPattern[MessageName[f_, _]] :> (m /. Messages[f])
```

The last code block in the preceding question uses this form.  That code also uses `Unevaluated` in the `FreeQ` expression since `` Internal`QuietStatus `` keeps messages in held form.  `Message` has the `HoldFirst` attribute, so additional holding is unnecessary there.

**Caution**

Patching internal low-level symbols like `Message` can have very subtle and far-reaching effects.  The issues discussed here are only the tip of the iceberg.  For example, the treatment of `$Off` would need to be generalized to handle cases when it takes the form `$Off["..."]`, or for when it is lazy-loaded.

Many internal system components fail in surprising ways if built-in functionality is disturbed in the slightest.  So techniques like these should not be used on a routine basis, but rather in specialized circumstances (e.g. debugging).

Comment: WReach, thank you! that is a really well written and detailed answer, as usual!

Comment: One more comment/question to the **Bonus Question** section: the message doesn't evaluate to a control string for most (all?) built-in symbols, such as `Power`, `Map`, `Plot` etc...  This is why I was confused with `LibraryFunction::overload` -- it does evaluate, but `Map::nonopt` etc. doesn't. Why is that/can the evaluation be enforced to eliminate that complex parsing with `First@ReleaseHold[...]`?

Comment: Obtaining message values for built-in kernel symbols has some subtle corner cases.  I have updated the discussion to address some of those issues.

Comment: Perfect answer, this explains it.