# How to make Mathematica only output the error name, rather than the full error message?

Tags: warning-messages, output-formatting, output

For example, when I use `LinearSolve`, an error message might be encountered:

```
LinearSolve::luc: Result for LinearSolve of badly conditioned matrix `1` may contain significant numerical errors.
```

where `` `1` `` is to be filled with the detailed badly-conditioined matrix.

The problem is that when that matrix is very big, then a very large error file will be generated. So is it possible to suppress the latter part and just keep the error name `LinearSolve::luc` printed out?

Comment: Related: [(1512)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1512), [(20367)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20367)

Comment: @Αλέξανδρος 我想问一下：你是哪个学校的，看你积分这么高，是川大的吗？

Answer (score 5):

```
<< GeneralUtilities`

WithMessageHandler[
 1/0, Print@#["MessageTemplate"] &
]
```

[image]

Does it fit your needs?

Keep in mind that with this handler the message isn't a message anymore so you can't `Check` it etc.

Comment: Not only "you can't `Check` it," but internal built-in code can't either, right? (I've never used `WithMessageHandler`, except to play with.)

Comment: Wait: `WithMessageHandler[
 Check[1/0, "Fudge!"],
 Print@#["MessageTemplate"] &]` seems to work fine.