# Is there a way to make Off[General::stop]'s effect only applied to some messages?

Tags: warning-messages

After Off[General::stop] it seems all kinds of messages start to print for as many as it need to. Is it possible to limit its effect to a selected set?

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/General/stop.html

Comment: Perhaps `AddHandler` could help you achieve whatever it is you seek. See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20371/46569 and its linked reference for some discussion.

Comment: @Goofy: Maybe, but all I need is to allow that message to be printed normally, i.e. I don't need to *handle* the message in any other way.

Comment: It does seem you want them handled in a nonstandard way, though. You also might be able to use `EvaluationData` depending on what your actual goal is. Usually I want to inspect the messages after the code is done, which you can do with `EvaluationData`, even the ones whose printing wes stopped by `General::stop`. But if your goal is to see them all printed to the notebook, then `EvaluationData` probably will be no help.

Comment: Right. Basically I'm mapping some operation on a list and want all errors to be displayed.