# How to get the error information after run a wrong expression

Tags: warning-messages, message-coding

If we run this code:

```
FindCycle[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

It will give a error information like:
[image]

How to get the error info promption of `FindCycle::argb: FindCycle called with 5 arguments; between 1 and 3 arguments are expected.`

---

As the comments,the method of Kuba's `FindCycle::argb /. Messages[FindCycle]` will get a ***string template*** with `` ` ` ``.The same case of [rcollyer's method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138699/how-to-get-the-error-information-of-function#comment374465_138699).But actually I want get a string(`..between 1 and 3 arguments..`) but not a string template(`` ..between `3` and `4` arguments.. ``).

Comment: @Kuba ok. I was wrong. Here's the [duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20032/52) ... which I wrote. :P

Comment: @Kuba here it is ``Internal`HandlerBlock[{"MessageTextFilter", Print[{##}] &}, 
 FindCycle[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]``. The first argument to `"MessageTextFilter"` gives the text.

Comment: @Kuba as an added warning, do not have `"Wolfram.System.Print"` use `Print`. The self eating loop is impressive, but requires you to kill the kernel externally. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54366/discussion-between-yode-and-rcollyer).

Comment: This seems to me like a duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20367/121

Comment: @rhermans I appreciate your idea to move all external images to imgur SE. May be it is better to introduce a delay into your script, so that SE users, question authors and the front page do not get overwhelmed by updates. Such updates can be done in the same way like Community user bumps random questions once an hour.

Comment: @Shadowray I didn't consider that, but clearly you rise a valid point. I sincerely apologise if I have caused a disruption. I'm very sorry.

Comment: @Shadowray,rhermans Bumps by Community is for draw attention.But this update for fix the incorrect composing.

Comment: @rhermans,yode I think this update is really good thing to do. I just suggest to update one question per hour (or so).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something different:

```
Attributes[getMsgString] = HoldFirst;

getMsgString[x_] := 
 Block[{MessagePacket =Return[ToString@ToExpression[#3[[1, 1, 3]]], Block] &}, x]
```

Now:

```
FindCycle[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] // getMsgString
```

> ```
> "FindCycle called with 5 arguments; between 1 and 3 arguments are expected. >>"
> ```

---

To address the case raised the comments here is one approach:

```
flatFraction = 
  StringReplace[#, 
    Shortest["\\!\\(" ~~ n__ ~~ "\\/" ~~ d__ ~~ "\\)"] :> n ~~ "/" ~~ d] &;

getMsgString[x_] := 
  Block[{MessagePacket =
    Return[#3[[1, 1, 3]] // flatFraction // ToExpression // ToString, Block] &}, x]

500 / 0 // getMsgString
```

> ```
> Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >>
> ```

Incidentally I copied the string above using **Plain Text**.  The direct output is:

> ```
> "Infinite expression \[NoBreak]1/0\[NoBreak] encountered. \[RightSkeleton]"
> ```

If that is a problem additional processing can be applied; let me know if you need help with that.

---

Edit for more general case

```
Attributes[getMsgString] = HoldFirst;

getMsgString[x_] := 
 Block[{MessagePacket = 
    Return[First[
       FrontEndExecute[
        FrontEnd`ExportPacket[
         First[MathLink`CallFrontEnd[
           FrontEnd`UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket[
            ToExpression[#3[[1, 1, 3]]], False]]], "PlainText"]]], 
      Block] &}, x]
```

#### Examples

[image]

---

More `MessagePacket` shenanigans:

- [Prepend Information to Warning Messages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8215/121)

Comment: I read all posts you linked,but I have to say your solution better than all of it.Just a preference for me.Your result not a [normal string](http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2017-02-27-15-22-40.png).If you can update a little,I will change the accepted.

Comment: I have given a little change in your code for concise,if you mind that,you can rollback it.Actually make `"Infinite expression \!\(\*FractionBox[\"1\", \"0\"]\) encountered."` into `"Infinite expression ∞ encountered."`.It's seem not easy to do.

Comment: @yode That is certainly possible on a case-by-case replacement but I suspect you mean more generally than that?  I'll edit my answer with one possible method.

Comment: @yode you should already know how to deal with string representation of expression inside strings: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138544/5478

Comment: @Kuba Funny,actually I have tried that method yesterday,it's not work.But I give another try just now.It work out.And have a update by your [this code](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138544/21532).

Comment: @yode `toText@toBoxes@
  "Infinite expression \!\(\*FractionBox[\"1\", \"0\"]\) encountered."`

Comment: I'm sorry,I make the answer be mess..

Answer (score 5):

The code below makes me think I have missed something obvious:

```
Quiet @Cases[
    Internal`HandlerBlock[
       {"Message", Sow}
     , Reap @ FindCycle[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
   ]
 , HoldPattern[Message[mn : MessageName[head_, name_], params___]] :> 
      StringTemplate[mn /. Messages[head]][params]
 , ∞
]
```

> ```
> {"FindCycle called with 5 arguments; between 1 and 3 arguments are \
>  expected."}
> ```

Comment: We can use ``Quiet[Internal`HandlerBlock[...]]`` to get same result.But I have to say I cannot totally understand your *mma syntax* here. :)

Comment: @yode I'm not sure what do you mean. Your short code returns: `{FindCycle[1,2,3,4,5],{{Hold[Message[FindCycle::argb,FindCycle,5,1,3],False]}}}` for me.

Comment: I mean [this](http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2017-02-27-03-01-24.png).

Comment: @yode Ok, now I understand, I though you meant I can use Quiet to make the code shorter :)