General::tag weird behavior
Is there anyone here who can explain this strange behavior? Consider the following code:
ClearAll[f]
General::generaltag = "This is a general message";
f::fspecifictag = "This is a f-specific message";

Then
General::generaltag
f::generaltag
f::fspecifictag

evaluates to

While the Message function works as expected despite the unevaluated middle expression,
Message[General::generaltag]
Message[f::generaltag]
Message[f::fspecifictag]

yielding

StringForm fails on the middle expression and ends up with

However, repeating definition of the General message name without prior ClearAll,
General::generaltag = "This is a general message";

will fix everything, giving for both
General::generaltag
f::generaltag
f::fspecifictag

and
StringForm[General::generaltag]
StringForm[f::generaltag]
StringForm[f::fspecifictag]


(the Message behavior remains unchanged). Reusing the the very first code with ClearAll would bring everything back to the original situation.
I appreciate any advice or tips.

Helpful?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20031/retrieving-the-text-of-a-message

Yes, thanks a lot!

This is (implicitly) explained in the documentation for General (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/General.html)

When you refer to a message with name s::tag in On or Off, the text of the message is obtained from General::tag if no specific message named s::tag exists.

You can infer from this that if a particular tag is missing from the Messgaes for the symbol, then the system will look for that tag in the Messages for General.
So, an easier way to reproduce this behavior is to just pick any tag associated to General and try it with f:
Message[f::argx]

You should see it attempting to produce a message based on General::argx.

It might also be worth mentioning that the search procedure performed by Message is described in the details of the docs for Message.  Also, General::generaltag = "..." sets a value associated with the symbol General, whereas f::generaltag would be a message value associated to the symbol f (which does not exist in the OP's scenario).
